# Python - gdal.Grid() correct use

Tags: python, raster, gdal, vrt

Is there any good, complete API for the GDAL Python bindings?

I am interpolating and rasterizing points with elevation data using the `gdal.Grid()` method;

```
output = gdal.Grid('outcome.tif','newpoints.vrt')
```

In its most basic sense, it's working perfectly. But now, I'd like to try the linear approach;

```
output = gdal.Grid('outcome.tif','newpoints.vrt', algorithm = 'linear:radius=0')
```

That does generate a new .tif file (512kb), but is just one big black image. Also, not all options seem to be accepted.. for the `invdist:power=4` for example it also results in a useless image. What is going wrong, am I missing something? Below is the .vrt I'm using;

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
<OGRVRTLayer name="newpoints">
    <SrcDataSource>newpoints.csv</SrcDataSource>
    <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
    <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="long" y="lat" z="depth"/>
</OGRVRTLayer>
```

**EDIT**
As a next example I used the `gdal.GridOptions()`, putting the parameters in that one. It is resulting in a correct file, but still ignores the options. How to actually pass the `GridOptions` onto the `gdal.Grid()` ?

**edit**
I found this question also; [GDAL grid produces NoData](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203819/gdal-grid-produces-nodata/203834) 
Is the linear interpolation just a bug in GDAL?

See my example workfiles;
https://gist.github.com/willemvanopstal/1eae4999fcfa62e89cca39a350b504d8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More info about [`gdal.Grid()`](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.Grid) and [`gdal.GridOptions()`](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.GridOptions) are available in the [**GDAL/OGR Python API**](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.html). Instead, here's the [available options of the interpolation algorithms](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html#interpolation-algorithms).
About the linear approach, this line (and more in detail the algorithm options `'linear:radius=0'`):

```
output = gdal.Grid('outcome.tif','newpoints.vrt', algorithm = 'linear:radius=0')
```

returns always NoData because:

> **radius:**
> In case the point to be interpolated does not fit into a triangle of the Delaunay triangulation, use that maximum distance to search a
> nearest neighbour, or use nodata otherwise. If set to -1, the search
> distance is infinite. **If set to 0, nodata value will be always used.**
> Default is -1.
>
> (Source: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html#interpolation-algorithms)

So, I'd try to use a better value of radius.

Note that the *"values to interpolate will be read from Z value of geometry record."* otherwise you will need to specify the `zfield` option:

> **zfield** --- Identifies an attribute field on the features to be used to
> get a Z value from. [...]
>
> (Source: https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.GridOptions)

Comment: that's surprisingly simple, will try it thanks! I just interpreted it as; in case the point is NOT in a triangle, only then the radius is taken into account.

Comment: still no success.. Tried multiple radii, all resulting in the same raster. INVDIST is working fine, together with its parameters. Should I use a CRS by definition? Although it also works without on the invdist? checkout: https://gist.github.com/willemvanopstal/1eae4999fcfa62e89cca39a350b504d8

Comment: I've just tried `'linear` and `'linear:radius=50'` and they work in both cases. Two observations: first, the `GeometryType` should be `wkbPoint25D` if you pass also the `z` coordinate, then defining also the `LayerSRS` is always a good design choice. What GDAL version are you using?

Comment: Revisiting the pointType resolves the problem.. confuses me, but hé it works. Thanks for investigating!