# Save scipy interpolations as a raster (GeoTIFF) format using Python

Tags: python, raster, interpolation

I am using `scipy.interpolate` (Python 3.9) to interpolate some data. However, after using a nearest neighbor interpolator, I need to save it as a raster (GeoTIFF) image, preserving the resolution of 0.5m x 0.5m. How can I do this?

The data needed to reproduce this [can be downloaded here.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12jCkFDuHDBODvQ0v4ebQMvBW_Ug5ji1E?usp=sharing) Total download size = 10 KB.

Here is the code I am using to generate my interpolations:

```
# Import modules
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'black'
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import box
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# Read in data
toad = pd.read_csv('stack_question_csv.csv')
bnd = gpd.read_file("stack_boundary_final.shp")

# Reproject shapefile boundary
bnd  = bnd.to_crs("epsg:4326")

# Convert DataFrame to GeoDataFrame
toad = gpd.GeoDataFrame(toad)
toad.head()

# Define coordinate systems
wgs84 = 4326 # WGS84

# Convert latitude and longitude to point data
toad['geometry'] = gpd.points_from_xy(toad['LON'], 
                                     toad['LAT'],
                                    crs = wgs84)

toad.head()

# Plotting of map boundary and sampled points
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(16,16))
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
bnd.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
toad.plot(ax=ax, marker='x', facecolor='k')
plt.show()

# Create grid
epsg_utm = 32614 # UTM Zone 14
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = bnd.to_crs(epsg=epsg_utm).total_bounds #Represents field in terms of meters

# Define cell size
xdelta = 0.5 # meters
ydelta = 0.5 # meters

# Create an empty array to save the grid
grid = np.array([])

for x in np.arange(xmin, xmax, xdelta): #min, max step
    for y in np.arange(ymin, ymax, ydelta): #min, max step
        cell = box(x,y, x+xdelta, y+ydelta)
        grid = np.append(grid, cell)
        
gdf_grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(grid, columns=['geometry'], crs=epsg_utm)
gdf_grid['centroids'] = gdf_grid['geometry'].centroid
gdf_grid.head()

# Convert CRS back to Lat/Long
gdf_grid['geometry'] = gdf_grid['geometry'].to_crs(crs=wgs84)
gdf_grid['centroids'] = gdf_grid['centroids'].to_crs(crs=wgs84)

gdf_grid.head()

# Clip cells
gdf_grid = gpd.clip(gdf_grid, bnd['geometry'].iloc[0])
gdf_grid.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

# Interpolate the values of observed weed density values to each centroid
x = toad['geometry'].x
y = toad['geometry'].y
z = toad['toads']

xq = gdf_grid['centroids'].x
yq = gdf_grid['centroids'].y

# Arrange variables in griddata input format
points = (x,y)
values = z
xi = (xq, yq)

toad_nn = griddata(points,
                    values,
                    xi,
                    method='nearest')

#Save interpoalted data values into the geodataframe
gdf_grid['toads'] = toad_nn.round(1)

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10,11))
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
gdf_grid.plot(ax=ax, 
              column='toads', 
              edgecolor='none', 
              cmap='RdYlGn',
             antialiased=False)
plt.show()

# Convert to UTM (EPGS:3721)
nad83 = 3721
gdf_grid['geometry'] = gdf_grid['geometry'].to_crs(crs=nad83)
gdf_grid['centroids'] = gdf_grid['centroids'].to_crs(crs=nad83)

gdf_grid.head()

print(gdf_grid.crs)
```

After running this code, I can export the data in WKT with `gdf_grid.to_csv('data_export.csv')`, but I wish to export the data as a raster layer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**

```
#Your code
...
plt.show()

#Skip the last 6 lines of your code.

import rasterio
from rasterio import features
import affine

width = int((xmax-xmin)/xdelta)
height = int((ymax-ymin)/ydelta)

transform = rasterio.transform.from_bounds(xmin, 
                                           ymin, 
                                           xmax, 
                                           ymax,
                                           width=width, 
                                           height=height)

gdf_grid['centroids'] = gdf_grid['centroids'].to_crs(crs=epsg_utm)
gdf2 = gdf_grid.drop('geometry', axis=1).values.tolist()

result = features.rasterize(
            gdf2,
            out_shape=(height, width), 
            transform=transform)

with rasterio.open(
        'rasterized.tif', 'w',
        driver='GTiff',
        dtype=rasterio.uint8,
        count=1,
        width=width,
        height=height,
        crs=gdf_grid.crs,
        transform = transform) as dst:
    dst.write(result, indexes=1)
```

The "export the data as a raster layer" part is not possible with a pure `geopandas` solution. I propose a solution using the library `rasterio` (another solution with `GDAL` is also possible).

In the code provided, the frequent conversions from one projection system to another using `geopandas.to_crs` function does not get reflected in the `dataframe.crs` property ([see pull request](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/1963)). Therefore, the last projection change can be avoided (see my code comment "Skip the last 6 lines of your code"). The remaining code is just preparing data for `rasterio's - rasterize and write` functions.

*Tip*: Try using [`GDAL's GRID`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/254334) function to convert from point layer to raster layer.